# Reinstall AutoCAD

Tags: autocad

I set up Autodesk AutoCAD  2012 in D partition, but last week the partition was damaged and I formatted this partition. Now I want to reinstall AutoCAD, but the setup program tell me that "this software is installed", but I can't find the software in "Programs and Features". I optimized and cleaned the PC with "[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)", but there is still a problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: i use windows 7-64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove any remnants of the product.[How to uninstall AutoCAD cleanly](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=18853994&linkID=9240897).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you but i use this help before post this question....this method not work....